# Vertical-Align - how does it works?

Tags: html, css, alignment

So there is code [on JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/2S2Qt/2/) and I can't make h1 inside of section to be ine the middle of the field... vertical align doesnt do his work! And margin auto same. Any1 has idea?

```
    #welcome{
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100px;
}
#welcome h1{
    color: gray;
    font-size: 2.1em;
    font-family:"proxima-nova","sans-serif";
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: vertical align doesnt work for block elements. h1 is a block element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set line-height on `#welcome h1` to the height in which you want to center the text, this is the typical way to center align text.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/xfRXX/)

```
#welcome h1 {
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you set line-height to same as div height it will vertical-align

```
#welcome{
height: 100px;
}
#welcome h1{
line-height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:table-cell`

```
section{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2S2Qt/3/)**